# Brace-or-equal initialization through a function call

Tags: c++, function, initialization, list-initialization

Although I think it wouldn't be a good practice, the compilers I use (both GNU and clang) seem to allow something like the following

```
      int f() {return 11;}

      class A {

          int a = f();
          public:
          int tell_me() {return a;}
              };
```

i.e. where a brace-or-equal initialization is made by calling a completely extraneous function.

Is this correct and allowed by the standard?
What about the collateral effects eventually introduced by the execution of `f()`?

Comment: Due to optimization，the compiler maybe replace f() with 11. if not optimize ,just as user2079303 answer.

Comment: you could use [constexpr specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) , compiler can be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct and allowed by the standard?

Yes.

> What about the collateral effects eventually introduced by the execution of f()?

Side-effects happen when the function is executed, which happens when an `A` is constructed. Exactly like they would if initialization list were used.